# What is the best setup for Xamarin player to communciate with a dev environment using vmware?

Tags: xamarin, vmware, hyper-v, vmware-workstation

I seem to hit a catch-22 situation. I have a windows 10 virtual machine set up within vmware workstation 12. On that VM is my full visual studio 15 development environment. This is my preferred dev environment and I do not wish to change it.

How can I use the above dev environment with the Xamarin android player?

- Installing it on the same VM as my dev environment is not supported
- Installing it on my host machine isn't acceptable because the xamarin player installation demands the disabling on hyper-V which will impact my vmware setup

What are my options for have xamarin player work with my VM?

Answer (score 0):

*One* option is to skip the 3rd-party Emulators (Xamarin, Visual Studios, Genymotion, etc...) and create a VMWare Android Guest and you can run your VisualStudio'15 Guest VM side-by-side of a Android Guest VM. As long as they share a network then Android's debug bridge (`adb`) can connect to it and thus Xamarin can connect to it.

The `Android-x86` site has the `.iso`'s and there are a number of blog posting around that walk you through the process of creating a Android-base d Guest VM.

- http://www.android-x86.org/download

FYI: Does the "vmx.allowNested = TRUE" not work in your situation?

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work exactly, but the xamarin player is full of dire warnings on how it isn't supported inside a VM

Comment: VS Android Emulator is Hyper-V compatible so you can run it in your host and network access from a guest....otherwise you are dealing with VirtualBox (Xammie and Genymotion) so using it in a nested-VM environment is not desirable, but....